# Optimize Binary Data Using Or Operator

Tags: optimization, binary, discrete-optimization

The purpose of this post is mainly for keywords for related researches.

---

Given $y_i\in \{0, 1\}$ and $x_i\in\{0,1\}^{n}$ for $i=1\ldots m$ and . 
How to solve the optimization problem
$$\begin{align} & \min_w \sum_{i=1}^{m} \left(sgn(x_i^Tw)-y_i\right)^2\\
\text{such that}\quad& \; w\in\{0,1\}^n,\end{align}$$
where $sgn(a)=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if } a>0 \\ 0 & \text{if } a\le 0\end{cases}$.

$w$ can be seen as a selector of $x_i$, and the selected $x_i$ are passed through a logical or gate and get the output.

For example, 
$y=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$, 
$X=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1^T \\ 
x_2^T \\
x_3^T \\
x_4^T \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$, then 
$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and
$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ are both solutions.

A simple way to solve is to try out every possible combinations, which is $2^n$ trials.
Are there any more scalable ways to solve this kind of problem? Or do you have any idea which research topic is related to it?

Comment: You have some indexing issues, and $x_i^T$ and $w$ have incompatible shapes.  Also, will the output of sgn be only 0 or 1 (and never -1)?

Comment: Thank you @RobPratt, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary decision variable $z_i$ represent $\text{sgn}(x_i^T w)$.  The objective function is then $$\sum_i (z_i-y_i)^2=\sum_i (z_i^2-2y_i z_i+y_i^2)=\sum_i (z_i-2y_i z_i+y_i)=\sum_i (1-2y_i) z_i+\sum_i y_i,$$ and the constraints are
$$z_i \le x_i^T w \le n z_i.$$
If $z_i=0$ then $x_i^T w=0$,
and if $z_i=1$ then $1 \le x_i^T w \le n$, as desired.